# How do I create a TestActorRef in Scala for an Actor with constructor params?

Tags: scala, testing, akka, actor

The [Akka Testing docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html) give the following way to create a TestActorRef:

```
import akka.testkit.TestActorRef

val actorRef = TestActorRef[MyActor]
```

How do I extend this for testing an existing actor that takes constructor arguments?  When I try running this as is, substituting in my actor class, I get the following error:

"error while creating actor
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException:Could not instantiate Actor
Make sure Actor is NOT defined inside a class/trait,
if so put it outside the class/trait, f.e. in a companion object,
OR try to change: 'actorOf(Props[MyActor]' to 'actorOf(Props(new MyActor)'."

The various ideas I could think up for adding the args after the class name inside the square brackets all crashed and burned, too.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could use [`Props`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.1.4/index.html#akka.actor.Props) like this:

```
val actorRef = TestActorRef(Props(new MyActor(param1, param2)))
```

Or factory method like this:

```
val actorRef = TestActorRef(new MyActor(param1, param2))
```

See `apply` methods in object [`TestActorRef`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.1.4/#akka.testkit.TestActorRef%24).

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick.  I added a type declaration to the val:

`val actorRef: TestActorRef[MyActor] = TestActorRef(Props(new MyActor(param1, param2)))`

and I'm now able to access it cleanly.

Comment: This seems to no longer work. Or at least isn't working for an actor declared inside of a test class.

Comment: @senia It seems that the problem I encountered is slightly different. See my new [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967398/how-to-create-a-testactorref-inside-a-test-class-for-an-actor-with-constructor-p) question.

Comment: Is there a real difference between these two methods are are they equivalent?

Comment: @k0pernikus, no since the second one is implemented using the first one: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/v2.5.19/akka-testkit/src/main/scala/akka/testkit/TestActorRef.scala#L132