# How to create a TestActorRef inside a test class for an Actor with constructor params?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

How does one create a TestActorRef inside a test class. Specifically, I have the following test set up...

```
class MatchingEngineSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("Securities-Exchange"))
  with FeatureSpecLike
  with GivenWhenThen
  with Matchers {

  val google = Security("GOOG")

  val ticker = Agent(Tick(google, None, None, None))

  val marketRef = TestActorRef(new DoubleAuctionMarket(google, ticker) with BasicMatchingEngine)

  val market = marketRef.underlyingActor
```

...when I run the tests everything passes, but after shutting down the ActorSystem I get this long error trace...

```
[ERROR] [03/10/2015 15:07:55.571] [Securities-Exchange-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka://Securities-Exchange/user/$$b]     Could not instantiate Actor
Make sure Actor is NOT defined inside a class/trait,
if so put it outside the class/trait, f.e. in a companion object,
OR try to change: 'actorOf(Props[MyActor]' to 'actorOf(Props(new MyActor)'.
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: exception during creation
```

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949348/how-do-i-create-a-testactorref-in-scala-for-an-actor-with-constructor-params) previous question, but the accepted answer didn't work for me in this case.

In case it is relevant, here is the definition of the `DoubleAuctionMarket` actor...

```
class DoubleAuctionMarket(val security: Security, val ticker: Agent[Tick]) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  this: MatchingEngine =>
  ...
```

Comment: How is your `DoubleAuctionMarket` actor defined?

Comment: I have updated the question to include information about the DoubleAuctionMarket actor.

Comment: Have you tried without the 'on the fly' mixin of `BasicMatchingEngine`? I don't see anything wrong with your code and your usage of `TestActorRef`.

Comment: Apologies, but I am new to both Scala and Akka. What exactly do you mean by "without the 'on the fly' mixin"?

Comment: That kind of self type reference restriction (`this:MatchingEngine =>`) is usually reserved for traits to make sure they are only mixed into certain types of classes.  What are you trying to accomplish with that setup on `DoubleAuctionMarket`?  Doing that on a class is forcing you do do a dynamic mix in at time of instantiation and I think that's the root of your problem.

Comment: I have implemented various different `MatchingEngines` for `DoubleAuctionMarkets`. The idea was to make it easy to swap out matching engines 'on the fly' so that I can compare model output across the various matching engines more easily (and avoid having a new `DoubleAuctionMarket` class for each `MatchingEngine.`  Up until now I thought it was an elegant use of self-typing...

Comment: `new DoubleAuctionMarket(google, ticker) with BasicMatchingEngine` this is the mixin.  Like @cmbaxter pointed out, I think that the self typing constraint in your actor is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue because I was using a companion object to inject the config into MyActor without passing it explicitly:

```
object MyActor {
  def apply(): MyActor = new MyActor(MyActorConfig.default)
  val props = Props(new MyActor(MyActorConfig.default))
}
```

Then I can just do:

```
val myActorRef = system.actorOf(MyActor.props, "actorName")
```

The error is related to passing the arguments explicitly in the test here:

```
TestActorRef(new DoubleAuctionMarket(google, ticker))
```

I would try to remove the `with BasicMatchingEngine` as vptheron said, use the constructor without mixing anything else. Try also with an argument less actor if that is not enough.

That must fix your problem since there are no issues with just:

```
TestActorRef(new DoubleAuctionMarket(google, ticker))
```